# Match words in string using negative lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I try to get words which don't start with **"un"** using pattern with negative lookbehind. This is the code:

```
using Regexp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex;
using RegexpOptions = System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions;

string quote = "Underground; round; unstable; unique; queue";
Regexp negativeViewBackward = new Regexp(@"(?<!un)\w+\b", RegexpOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection finds = negativeViewBackward.Matches(quote);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", finds));
```

It always returns full set of words, but should return only **round, queue**.

Comment: if the word separator is always `;` you don't even have to use regular expressions - `String.Split` combined with linq would do the job

Comment: Note there is `Regex` class, not `Regexp`.

Comment: What's the point aliasing `Regex` as `Regexp`? And `RegexpOptions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?<!un)\w+\b` first matches a location that is not preceded with `un` (with the negative lookbehind), then matches 1 or more word chars followed with a word boundary position.

You need to use a *negative lookahead* after a leading word boundary:

```
\b(?!un)\w+\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F!un%29%5Cw%2B%5Cb&i=Underground%3B%20round%3B%20unstable%3B%20unique%3B%20queue&o=i).

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!un)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next two word chars are `un`
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/7RbxsL):

```
string quote = "Underground; round; unstable; unique; queue";
Regex negativeViewBackward = new Regex(@"\b(?!un)\w+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List<string> result = negativeViewBackward.Matches(quote).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach (string s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
round
queue
```